# Concatenate Variable in a string Jquery

Tags: jquery, string, laravel, concatenation

I have a laravel project and using an ajax call, I need the Edit button link to be rendered correctly so I have this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/client/all", 
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result){
    var myObj = $.parseJSON(result);
    $.each(myObj, function(key,value) {
        var t = $('#clientsList').DataTable();
        t.row.add( [
            value.id,
            value.ClientName,
            value.TradingName,
            value.ClientCode,
            value.ClientOwner,
            '<a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="{{ URL::to("client'+value.id+'/edit") }}">Edit</a>',

        ] ).draw();

    });
}});
```

But when I inspect element it, edit link shows

```
<a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="http://localhost/dboard/public/client'+value.id+'/edit">Edit</a>
```

the + doesn't concatenate value.id in the string. Did I missed something or have wrong syntax? thanks

Comment: The syntax should be right: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rx2mw1zr/). Is `value.id` existing ? There might be an issue with the `.add()`-function of `DataTable`

Comment: value.id is correct. It's showing fine in my table even if i change the variable name it still outputing the variable name not the value itself. It is appending the '+value.id+' in the string instead of using the value of value.id

Comment: Maybe try creating a string variable above the t.row.add that contains the link and just add the string instead of having to concatenate it while adding it?

Comment: The samething happens

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit your concatenation to the following:

```
"<a class='btn btn-small btn-info' href='{{ URL::to('client'"+value.id+'"/edit') }}'>Edit</a>"
```

Try it, hope it helps. Otherwise let me know I will modify it again.